# Should a development team use a single pair of repo.magento.com keys?

Tags: magento2, deploy, key

I understand that in order to use `composer` with Magento 2, you need to set up your instance with a public key and private key per the documentation. If you’re working in a team, should the team use the same pair of authentication keys, or should each developer have their own unique pair?

Comment: Each developer its own pair and one pair each (of lead? or company account) for develop, stage, test system, live, ...

Answer (score 2):

Unique pair.

Much easier to remove a single developer key pair than it is to reissue keys to the WHOLE dev team…

Comment: where those key pairs are saved which we can remove individually ?

Answer (score 1):

Each developer its own pair and one pair each (of lead? or company account) for develop, stage, test system, live, ...

Answer (score 0):

**COMPOSER.
HTTP basic authentication**

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md

The file should contain a set of hostnames followed each with their own username/password pairs, for example:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.example1.org": {
            "username": "my-username1",
            "password": "my-secret-password1"
        },
        "repo.example2.org": {
            "username": "my-username2",
            "password": "my-secret-password2"
        }
    }
}
```

> multiuser environment

```
[root@web src]# su developer -s /bin/bash -c "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition ."
Authentication required (repo.magento.com):                                                                                                      
      Username: 239874679544d0c72c8cfd5c60b12
      Password: 
Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in /home/developer/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn] y
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.0.2)
Proceeding without cache
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.0.2)
    Downloading: Connecting...^C
Session terminated, killing shell...^C ...killed.



[root@web src]# composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username: 95483g8747733gok2c8cfd5c60b12
      Password: 
Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in /root/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn]
```

If you don't provide the authentication credentials composer will prompt you upon connection to enter the username and password.

Comment: Thanks - but that looks like it’s per repo, not per user. I’m asking about multiple users for a single repo.

Comment: hm, have you read at the very bottom??

Comment: in a perfect world you must have master or root account, then another for developer, another for sub-contractors, etc... dont say you have one root account for everyone?

Comment: That’s what I’m asking. It’s unclear from your example above if you’re running that 2nd create project as a different user, but you’re writing to the same auth.jason file… so how does the auth.jason file manage when multiple users are connecting to the same repository? Also, once you’ve set up your team, if someone leaves, how would you remove their keys? thx!

Comment: you not writing to the same file, but every user have its own file to authenticate!!

Comment: Ah I see! thx - so how would you revoke a users keys if they were no longer on the project?